# Different h264 encoders in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, android-ffmpeg

In `ffmpeg` 4.0, there are several h264 encoders. If you use `./configure --list-encoders | grep "h264"`, you can see them.

- h264_amf
- h264_nvenc
- h264_omx
- h264_qsv
- h264_v4l2m2m
- h264_vaapi
- h264_videotoolbox

**I do not know what's the difference between.** And I want convert local gif to mp4 using ffmpeg, so which encoder works for me?

Comment: None Those all depend on specific hardware or platform. You need `libx264`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's better if you can explain these encoder.

Comment: videotoolbox is Apple devices, nvenc is Nvidia, you can google the rest.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Each encoder use a different API to access video hardware :

- h264_amf to access AMD gpu, (windows only)
- h264_nvenc use [nvidia gpu cards](https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg) (work with windows and linux)
- h264_omx raspberry pi encoder
- h264_qsv use [Intel Quick Sync Video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync) (hardware embedded in modern Intel CPU)
- h264_v4l2m2m use [V4L2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux) Linux kernel api to access hardware codecs
- h264_vaapi use [VAAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Acceleration_API) which is another abstraction API to access  video acceleration hardware (Linux only)
- h264_videotoolbox use [videotoolbox](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/videotoolbox) an API to access hardware on macOS

With proper hardware, each encoder will succeed to encode your decoded gif to mp4.

You can custom this command to convert gif to mp4 :

```
$ ffmpeg -i local-gif.gif -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

libx264 is the default encoder which does not use any specific hardware this can be changed to the desired encoder.

Comment: amf is windows only, nvenc (win/linux), and vaapi linux only, can you add these ietails to your response to make it more exhaustive?